# How to view Chrome settings on XVFB?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker, proxy, xvfb

I'm using [Chrome in a Docker container](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/NodeChromeDebug) (published by SeleniumHQ) to run automated tests in the Cloud. This runs a minimal display environment on [XVFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) that you can [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) into to see results.

Now we're using this within a Corporate firewall - and so external requests need to go through a proxy. We're setting the proxy with the [Selenium proxy command](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#chrome).

Now we've run a test on the command line with curl on the Chrome docker container and curl with the proxy can access external resources just fine. But Chrome has an unknown problem accessing external resources (internal are fine). When we try and look at the settings, it is locked out. (Something about not being about the render the settings on xvfb).

So I'm looking for a way to look at the settings similar to Firefox's `about:config`. Now obviously this doesn't work on Chrome, but there appear to be some similar things.

There appear to be some details on [URLs to use here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23424).

They suggest:

[chrome://net-internals/proxyservice#events](http://chrome://net-internals/proxyservice#events)

[chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.config#events](http://chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.config#events)

[chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.init_log#events](http://chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.init_log#events)

[chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.bad_proxies#events](http://chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.bad_proxies#events)

My question is: **How to view Chrome settings on XVFB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see the current preferences is to open the file `scoped_dir5752_14079\Default\Preferences` in the temporary folder once the session is started.

And for a list and description of the preferences :

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Comment: Cool - where is the temporary folder? (On Ubuntu)

Comment: It should be `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`

Comment: Cool - interestingly enough - this doesn't show the proxy settings - but this is effectively the same as the about:config. Well done.